# Drools : how to assign value to variable "from" predefined method when using PackageDescr to generate rule?

Tags: drools

How can I generate something like this in my rule using PackageDescr ?

```
$var: Number (doubleValue > 100 ) from myPredefinedFunction()
```

I tried the following :

```
PatternDescr pt = new PatternDescr("Number","$var");
RelationalExprDescr ex = new RelationalExprDescr(">", false, null, new ExprConstraintDescr("myPredefinedFunction()"), new ExprConstraintDescr("100"));
pt.addConstraint(ex);
```

but this is what I get :

```
 $var : Number( myPredefinedFunction() > 100 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set the `myPredefinedFuntion()` as a constraint. Constraints are the part of the drools declaration between the parentheses, eg. `MyObject( foo == "bar" )` ... the `foo == "bar"` is a constraint.

Instead you need to set the source using the [`setSource`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.drools/drools-compiler/7.44.0.Final/org/drools/compiler/lang/descr/PatternDescr.html#setSource-org.drools.compiler.lang.descr.PatternSourceDescr-) method. This is the 'from' part of the declaration. This method takes a instance of a [`PatternSourceDescr`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.drools/drools-compiler/7.44.0.Final/org/drools/compiler/lang/descr/PatternSourceDescr.html) subclass -- likely a [`FromDescr`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.drools/drools-compiler/7.44.0.Final/org/drools/compiler/lang/descr/FromDescr.html) for this particular scenario.

(Alternatively, you might need `setResource` instead of `setSource`. The problem with using internal-only APIs is that they're not documented and subject to change without notice. I strongly suggest not going down this route.)